# How to connect AWS lambda with Aerospike db cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aerospike

I have a requirement, in which an excel file is being uploaded to S3 bucket, so as soon as that file gets uploaded, I want to trigger a lambda function which will read that excel file and then persist the data in aerospike db.

For reading the excel file, I have got this piece of code

```
key = 'key-name'
bucket = 'bucket-name'
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_object = s3_resource.Object(bucket, key)

data = s3_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()

lines = csv.reader(data)
headers = next(lines)
print('headers: %s' %(headers))
for line in lines:
    #print complete line
    print(line)
```

But I not able to figure out how to connect to aerospike db, as boto3 library doesn't support aerospike.

Please help me in connecting to db cluster and persist the data ?
Or any reference would be helpful

Answer (score 4):

I think the way to interact with Aerospike from something like AWS Lambda is to use the Aerospike REST Client that provides a server which translates Restful API requests into messages to an Aerospike Cluster (it is mentioned in the blog post).

Basically you can run a REST server (Aerospike REST Client) that you can send HTTP requests from AWS Lambda using Python to the server and the server will translate these requests to Aerospike operations and will be responsible of executing them.

This is the GitHub repository of Aerospike REST Client - it also contains couple of blog posts of how to use it and a Swagger UI documentation of the actual supported requests:
https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-rest

There is also this blog post of Serverless Event Stream Processing with Aerospike which can help you get started:
https://medium.com/aerospike-developer-blog/serverless-event-stream-processing-with-aerospike-679f2a5cbba6

Comment: Yeah, lately I also figured out about REST client. Can I do this using Spring boot application which will contain all the dependencies for aerospike client and then upload it as a ZIP file in Lambda. Is it the right approach to do this ?

Comment: I’m not sure, didn’t try it myself. I guess you could try to use an Aerospike Client SDK (Java/Python) or a framework that wraps a client SDK (Spring Data Aerospike) in your AWS Lambda and if that doesn’t work try the REST Client. The drawback with the REST Client is that you need to start another server that runs it but the benefit is that the Lambda will only need to be able to reach this server and will not require any dependency - it will just send a simple REST call using any language of your choice.